# Exclude Xenu's Link Sleuth from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, xenu

I've just added the Google Analytics tracking to my website (cca 350 static HTML pages).

I realized that I run Xenu's Link Sleuth to check my links pretty often, nearly after each change in my HTML files. I guess such checking will be counted as regular accesses to my website by Google Analytics. I would like to exclude the Xenu checking from the Google Analytics reports. Is this possible?

So far, I have excluded my own access by filtering out my IP address. Can I do something similar for the Xenu? I am running the Xenu application always from my own PC, does it mean that by excluding my own IP, I have also excluded the Xenu checking, which is possibly using also my IP address?

As I am writing this, I am realizing that I am using also online HTML validator at http://validator.w3.org/ and another version here http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/. Can I somehow exclude also these checks?

Answer (score 2):

Does Link Sleuth run JavaScript? If not, it won't do anything to Google Analytics.

From what I can see [on the FAQ](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html#FAQ), Link Sleuth will only run JavaScript if you tell it to, and then only links that match your regular expression. Just don't get it to call the GA tracker.